# Biderectional relations in POJOs (parent <=> children)

Tags: android, android-room

Is it possible to have bidirectional relations in POJOs in room?

Like in following test I've written:

```
data class TestChildWithRefs(
    @Embedded val child: TestChild,
    // REMOVING following reverse relation solves the problem; only referenceing TestParent instead of TestParentWithRefs also works but is not what I need
    @Relation(parentColumn = "fk_parent", entityColumn = "parent_id", entity = TestParent::class)
    val parent: TestParentWithRefs
)

data class TestParentWithRefs(
    @Embedded val parent: TestParent,
    @Relation(parentColumn = "parent_id", entityColumn = "fk_parent", entity = TestChild::class)
    val children: MutableList<TestChildWithRefs>
)
```

As soon as I add bidirectional relations, room stops building with a `StackOverflowError` because of endless recursions. Can I somehow solve this?

I need this because my data layer will expose parents and childrens via already defined interfaces and those allow to retrieve navigate from parent to children as well as the other way round...

**Additonal code:**

```
// ------
// Child entity + dao
// -----

@Entity(tableName = "child")
data class TestChild(
        @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true) @ColumnInfo(name = "child_id") var id: Long = 0L,
        @ColumnInfo(name = "name") var name: String,
        @ColumnInfo(name = "fk_parent") var fkParent: Long
)

@Dao
abstract class TestChildDao {
    @Transaction
    @Query("SELECT * FROM child")
    abstract fun loadAll(): List<TestChildWithRefs>
}

// ------
// Parent entity + dao
// -----

@Entity(tableName = "parent")
data class TestParent(
        @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true) @ColumnInfo(name = "parent_id") var id: Long = 0L,
        @ColumnInfo(name = "name") var name: String
)
@Dao
abstract class TestParentDao {
    @Transaction
    @Query("SELECT * FROM parent")
    abstract fun loadAll(): List<TestParentWithRefs>
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I found a way to model bidirectional relations in room, with a little (but acceptable) manual interaction.

Here's my example based on my real solution:

- 1 day (parent) => has many workouts
- 1 workout (child) => has many exercises
- 1 exercise (child of child) => I'll stop at this level, the example explains the idea

**Entity wrappers with working bidirectional relations**

```
 class FullDay(
    @Embedded
    val day: WDay,

    @Relation(parentColumn = "w_day_id", entityColumn = "fk_day", entity = WWorkout::class)
    val workouts: MutableList<FullWorkout> = ArrayList()
) {
     fun setRefs() {
        workouts.forEach { it.setRefs(this) }
    }
}

class FullWorkout(
    @Embedded
    val workout: WWorkout,

    @Relation(parentColumn = "w_workout_id", entityColumn = "fk_workout", entity = WExercise::class)
    val internalExercises: MutableList<FullExercise> = ArrayList()
) {

    @Ignore
    var day: FullDay? = null

    fun setRefs(day: FullDay) {
        this.day = day
        internalExercises.forEach { it.setRefs(this) }
    }
}

class FullExercise(

    @Embedded
    val exercise: WExercise

    // ...

) {
    @Ignore
    var workout: FullWorkout? = null

    fun setRefs(fullWorkout: FullWorkout) {
        this.workout = fullWorkout
    }
}
```

**working dao**

```
@Dao
abstract class WDao : BaseDao {

    companion object {
        const val BASE_QUERY = "SELECT * FROM w_day " +
                "left join w_workout on w_day_id = fk_day " +
                "left join w_exercise on w_exercise_id = fk_exercise " +
                "left join w_set on w_exercise_id = w_set_fk_exercise " +
                "left join w_target_set on w_exercise_id = w_target_set_fk_exercise"
    }

    // ------------------
    // internal functions
    // ------------------

    @Transaction
    @Query("$BASE_QUERY where w_day_id = :id")
    abstract fun _loadFullDay(id: Long): FullDay

    @Transaction
    @Query("$BASE_QUERY where date = :date")
    abstract fun _loadFullDayOfDate(date: Date): FullDay?

    @Transaction
    @Query("$BASE_QUERY where w_workout_id = :id")
    abstract fun _loadFullWorkout(id: Long): FullDay

    @Transaction
    @Query("$BASE_QUERY where date >= :date")
    abstract fun _loadFullWorkoutAfterDate(date: Date): List<FullDay>

    @Transaction
    @Query("$BASE_QUERY where w_exercise_id = :id")
    abstract fun _loadFullExercise(id: Long): FullDay

    // ------------------
    // external functions
    // ------------------

    fun loadFullDay(id: Long): FullDay = _loadFullDay(id).apply { setRefs() }
    fun loadFullDayOfDate(date: Date): FullDay? = _loadFullDayOfDate(date)?.apply { setRefs() }
    fun loadFullWorkout(id: Long): FullWorkout = _loadFullWorkout(id).apply { setRefs() }.workouts.first()
    fun loadFullWorkoutAfterDate(date: Date): List<FullWorkout> = _loadFullWorkoutAfterDate(date).onEach { it.setRefs() }.map { it.workouts }.flatten()
    fun loadFullExercise(id: Long): FullExercise = _loadFullExercise(id).apply { setRefs() }.workouts.first().internalExercises.first()

}
```